# GoogleVM - Remote Desktop Connection Error

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, remote-access, remote-desktop-services, 500-error

Can't connect to Google Server using Remote Desktop Connection in Windows 10.
The error is "An internal error has occurred".

Comment: Please provide more information. Are trying to access this VM from Google Console using the RDP option? If not Could you provide in a High Level how are you trying to connect to.

Comment: Hi, Im just using the Remote desktop connection of windows using the Remote credentials host, username and password. Before it has no problem. Thanks in advance @ArdenSmith